# Agregar a una tabla los datos de input mediante jquery

Tags: jquery, html5

Hola estoy intentando agregar datos de un formulario a una tabla, sin embargo cuando le doy click al botón agregar me captura los valores en cero. El código es el siguiente:

Pagar
                    
                         
                    
              
              
                  Forma de pago
                  EfectivoTarjeta de Crédito / DébitoChequeOtro
             
              
                    Voucher
                    
                         
                    
              
             
                   
                    Agregar pago

```
              </thead>
              <tbody id="bodypago">

              </tbody>  
            </table>

          </div> 
        </div>
  </div> 
   </div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
   var cantpa= $("#cantpa").val();
   var tipopa = $("#micombo").val();
    $("#addpa").on('click', function(e){
        $("#bodypago").append("<tr><td>"+cantpa+"</td><td>"+tipopa+"</td></tr>");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes proporcionarnos mayor dato de los datos a cargar?

Comment: La tabla se debe generar dinamicamente, escribo en el input doy click en boton agregar y se agrega a la tabla, el detalle es que cuando doy click en el boton se agrega en 0 y no me reconoce lo que digitado en el input, lo hago de la siguiente manera descrita en el codigo anexo de arriba

Comment: alli lo edite por que no se percibia bien, dejame checkar

Comment: puedes mostrar la parte del html donde tiene el id cantpa, micombo y el boton? Ademas de apretar f12 y mostrar la consola de errores para verificar que es lo que te sale?

Comment: no veo los input en el html, al no existir los input en html no capturara nada.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var cantpa= $("#cantpa").val(); 
var tipopa = $("#micombo option:selected").val(); //Creo que es un select
$("#addpa").click(function(){ 
   $("#bodypago").append($("<tr>").append(
     "<td>" + cantpa +  "</td>" +
     "<td>" + tipopa + "</td>"
   )); 
});
```

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: Es prácticamente lo mismo que el código original del autor, aquí el problema es más bien cómo está obteniendo los valores, probablemente se deba a un error de ids o de tipo de input.

Comment: Todo es probable, sin embargo, el código fue editado si te fijas en el post, sólo queda esperar :)

Comment: por lo mismo habrá que esperar a que muestre bien de donde vienen los datos y el botón, por que incluso puede ser solo un error en tipificar. Pero mientras no de mas datos, poco y nada podemos responder :)

Answer (score 0):

Debes de poner tus variables adentro del evento click para que así tengan valores, de lo contrario al finalizar la creación del DOM las variables no van a tener valores y esto se va a ver reflejado.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#addpa").on('click', function(e) {
            var cantpa = $("#cantpa").val();
            var tipopa = $("#micombo").val();
            alert(cantpa + 'click' + tipopa);
            $("#bodypago").append("<tr><td>" + cantpa + "</td><td>" + tipopa + "</td></tr>");
        });
    </script>
```

Ahora si necesitas las variables de manera global puedes utilizar el siguiente código.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let cantpa;
    let tipopa
    $("#addpa").on('click', function(e) {
        cantpa = $("#cantpa").val();
        tipopa = $("#micombo").val();
        alert(cantpa + 'click' + tipopa);
        $("#bodypago").append("<tr><td>" + cantpa + "</td><td>" + tipopa + "</td></tr>");
    });
</script>
```

Recomendación cambiar las variables tipo `var` por `let`.